# Wiring WS2812b to power supply

Tags: led, ws2812b, awg

I currently have am trying to power a 300M 5V WS2812b from only one end from a 5v 20A power switching supply that I got off ebay. There is about 8-10 feet of distance between the two, and I was wondering what guage wire should be used in order for this to be safe.

I have been told by some that use CAT6 cables would be fine, but I have doubts around this. I was thinking more like 16AWG wire.

Not too sure if this length is too long though. I am trying to avoid having a buck converter or power supply near the LEDs for aesthetic reason.

Thanks!

Comment: To help get some answers, perhaps you could add a link to the LED strip and also quote the current requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longer the wire, the more resistance you have.  This is a known quantity that can easily be calculated by several online [calculators](https://www.cirris.com/learning-center/calculators/133-wire-resistance-calculator-table).

For instance, using the linked calculator, and assuming 10 feet of 24 gauge wire (typical ethernet cable), resistance added by the wire is 0.257 ohms.  V=IR tells us that the voltage drop in the wire due to current is proportional to the resistance.  It seems that a single LED can draw up to 50mA.  V=0.05*0.257=0.0129V drop.

As you pull more current, that voltage drop number goes up.  So, at the end of 10 feet, if you started out with 5V, by the time you get to the LED, you would only have 4.9871V.  Not a big deal since the voltage on these LEDs needs to be above 3.3V.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!

If I have 300 LEDs at 50mA each, then the total MAX amp pull would be 1500mA, which would be V=1.5*0.257=0.3855. Would this voltage drop be at the first LED, or be at the last LED? Or can I assume that the power entering the LED strip would be with the 0.0129V drop?

Also, are there any issues with overheating when running wires too thin off a 5v 20A power supply? I do plan on putting in 2 10A breakers just to be safe, and powering two of the 300 5M led strips off the single supply.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The voltage drop would be at the end of the 10 feet of wire since it is basically a long resistor.  If you had LEDs wired throughout the 10 feet, then there would be different voltage drops based on where they are connected (think of a resistor with a movable contact, like a potentiometer).  If you start wiring LEDs at the end of the 10 feet, then your voltage drop would be at the first LED.

Comment: So even if the first LED only takes in 50ma, the actual voltage drop would be the voltage drop at the first LED would be based on 15,000ma because that's the actual amp pull of 300 LEDs?

Comment: Right.  For your heat question, wire is usually rated by amps.  Since you have so many LEDs, you will probably need something bigger than 24AWG.  15 amps requires some hefty wire.  You might want to split it across multiple wires.  [Here](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) is a reference for wire sizing.

Comment: To expand on that a little more, whenever you have a voltage drop in the wire, it generates heat.  If you have enough voltage drop, the wire gets too hot and melts.  That's the general idea behind a fuse.  The more voltage drop, the more heat.  The goal is to have as little voltage drop as possible.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying and the detailed answers!